# Scroll Div Within another Scrolling Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm in bit of a pickle here.. So I have rows of divs, think of them as mini boxes. I'm able to scroll through them within a specified width/height area. using : http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

Now, within one of those Div, I have more content that I'd like to scroll within that Div. And that is where the problem arises. No matter what I do, I just can't achieve it.

Here is an example skeleton:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.rows{
    margin:50px auto;   width:400px; height:405px; overflow:auto;
}
.row{
  background: lightblue; height: 370px; width: 320px; margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.column{
  float:left;
}
.columns{
    margin:50px auto;   width:800px; height:405px; 
}
</style>

<DIV id="container">

  <DIV class="columns">
    <DIV class="column">
      <DIV class="rows"> <div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div> </DIV>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="column">
      <DIV class="rows">  <div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div> </DIV>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="column">
      <DIV class="rows">  <div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div> </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>

  <link href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>


        $(window).load(function(){

            $(".rows").mCustomScrollbar({
                scrollButtons:{ enable:false }
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

====================

To clarify further, within the div class "row", I'll have lets say a long paragraph that needs to be scrolled within that box.

Thanks

======================

JS/CSS links:

```
http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js
http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mousewheel.min.js
http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js
http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css
```

Comment: please set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ version of the code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bjHUf/ here is the fiddle, I'm still not sure what's the issue here. if you want this answered, edit the fiddle into the test case you need.

Comment: Hi, I tried setting up the jsfiddle, but it appears in the way it has for you, it doesn't seem to load the jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js plugin properly. Anyhow the problem is. I need to do nested scrolling. In that within one of the blue boxes, I'd have lets say a long paragraph that I need to be able to scroll. Do I make sense? Maybe I'll draw up an image as that may be much clearer. On another note, I posted the question to the creator of the JS plugin : https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/14 and as per him, currently the plugin doesn't support nested scroll...